# Unable to get property 'hide' jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Why i have error with internet explorer for this code, with all other browser this working fine, only IE is problem

```
Unable to get property 'hide' of undefined or null reference
Unable to get property 'show' of undefined or null reference
```

code

```
if(data.button) {
    this.mouseenter(function()
    {
        $button.hide();
    });

    this.mouseleave(function()
    {
        $button.show();
    });
}
```

Rest of code

```
var onload = function()
    {
        $this.unbind('load', onload);

        $wrap = $('<div id="profile_changer_wrap"/>');

    $this.wrap($wrap);
        if(data.data['type'] == 'avatar'){
            var lngEdit = 'Edit Profile Image';
            var class_c = 'profile_img';
        }else if(data.data['type'] == 'banner'){
            var lngEdit = 'Edit Cover Image'
            var class_c = 'cover_img';
        };  
        $button = $('<div id="profile_changer_button" class="'+class_c+'">'+lngEdit+'</div>').insertAfter($this);

    $button.css(
    {
        'top': ($this.outerHeight(true) - $button.height())/2 - 5,
        'left': ($this.outerWidth(true) - $button.width())/2 - 10
    });
};
```

Comment: We might need to see more code like the data object

Comment: Where is this $button variable coming from? We need to see the whole code involved to give you a appropriate answer.

Comment: Did you declare `$button` as a global variable?

Comment: You said that it work fine in other browsers, the only problem is IE (as always :/ ). How are you binding the `onload` function? are you using jQuery? window.onload? or `addEventListener`?

Comment: Yeah working fine with all browser only IE is problem, it'a a jQuery

Comment: It sounds like jQuery isn't being included on your page in IE. Are you  on an https:// but linking your jQuery.js with http://? If so, you might try replacing https:// with simply //. Do you have a link to share?

Comment: yes included from google cdn, but something is happend with this 1.83 version at google server.. hmm strange...
I just test at local PC with same version and script is working fine with IE.. :( anyway, it's a jQuery problem...